# python3's "pdfkit"-import keeps destroying german umlaute

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, pdfkit

Hey people and codingfriends.

Im currently writing a little tool in python3 which i want to write some userinput from a .txt-file into a pdf-file. For this i am using "pdfkit". Im first writing my input into a 2nd. txt file, because i need the output in a special form and with "pdfkit.from_string(source, destination.pdf)" it doesnt seem to work properly. So im Writing it first into a 2nd txt file how i already said and then converting it with "pdfkit.from_file("source.txt", destination.pdf)". I already sorted out the problem with the different unicodestuff but somehow the "pdfcreator" keeps deleting/changing all "umlaute". I guess i can figure out why it keeps doing that, but i cant cant find a solution due its a 3rd party import. The createt txt file btw is in exactly the form i need it, just the pdf stuff is not working.

In example:

[image: for this output .txt]

[image: ..i am getting this converted .pdf]

Does anyone have a solution for me?

For me would also work:

- writing from python into a different txt format which is easy to convert into pdf (with umlaute!)
- OR
- using a 3rd party-software which i am calling from python to convert my txt file

So far i got this code(including some readLines methods which are also working pretty well - i guess):

```
def dok2pdf(fileName):
dokument=open(fileName, "r", encoding="latin-1").read()

for line in dokument:
    if line==" ":
        dokument=dokument.replace(line, " ")
    if line==";":
        dokument=dokument.replace(line, "\n")

file = open("tryhard.txt","w")
file.write(dokument)
file.close() 


pdfkit.from_file("tryhard.txt", 'tryhard.pdf')
```

thanks a lot.